# Rotate ImageView in Android around a fixed point using RotateAnimation

Tags: android, rotation, imageview, fixed-point, rotateanimation

I'd like to rotate an image 360 degrees continuously around a fixed point. I've seen a few examples already such as:

```
RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0, 360,150,150);
anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
anim.setDuration(2000);
[imageview].startAnimation(anim);
```

This does rotate the image, but it does so on an arc/circular path. Ie. the image is moving/rotating in a circular motion but isn't staying fixed at it's starting location.

What I basically want is to mimic the rotation of a WindMill's arms.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7):

Use this code

```
RotateAnimation rotateAnimation1 = new RotateAnimation(0, 360,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
rotateAnimation1.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
rotateAnimation1.setDuration(duration);
rotateAnimation1.setRepeatCount(0);
img.startAnimation(rotateAnimation1);
```

this will rotate your image on its fixed position, i.e. around itself

Comment: i need rotation for handle up and down like i drag handle down and up

Comment: akhir kehna kya chahte ho?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I got this working perfectly after some tweaking. Like Macarse said, it did involve the padding around the `ImageView`.

To fix this issue, all you have to do is put your `ImageView` inside a `RelativeLayout`:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/image"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

i will say set the pivot point of imageview.. to the x = imgView.getWidth()/2, and y = imgView.getHeight()/2